# Using a char when creating a new object

Tags: java, object, char

I have a Student class where I need to have grade as a character when creating an object. How do I write that in the object parameters? If I use quotes it thinks it's a string, and if i just write the grade A, it thinks it's a variable. Parameters are:

```
String name
String Adress
Integer birthdate
Integer age
String course
char grade
String school

Student Student1 = new Student("John", "Random street 1", 891117, 23, "Java", A, "HIG" );
```

Comment: just use 'a' for characters

Comment: I suggest you use `int` instead of `Integer` for age and `Date` or `long` instead of `Integer` for birthdate. I suggest you use `address`  instead of Adress

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chars are wrapped within single quotes `'`

```
Student Student1 = 
new Student("John", "Random street 1", 891117, 23, "Java", 'A', "HIG" );
```

Comment: You mean single quotes?

Answer (score 0):

And if you are interested in wrapper class , you can use something like this

```
Character myChar=new Character('a');
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use

Student Student1 = new Student("John", "Random street 1", 891117, 23, "Java", 'A', "HIG" );

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should use `enum`s here since the list of grades are fixed:

```
public enum Grade{
    A, B, C, D, E F;
}
```

Then you can just pass `Grade.A` for example.